# render view model on item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, render

The situation is as follows: I have a `Product` model which has many properties and one is a List of `Photo` objects, each `Photo` object having an `ID` and a `Name`. There is a Carousel View having a model a list of `Photos`. In `Product` View I have something like this:

```
@if (Model.Photos.Count > 0)
{
    ....
    <a href="javascript:jsFunction()".......
```

Where in javascript,the `jsFunction` looks like this:

```
function jsFunction()
{
  alert('@Html.Action("GetPhotosCarousel", Model.Photos)');
}
```

and the Controller function returns the partial view `_PhotosCarousel`.

Now, the problem that `@Html.Action` executes on rendering the main view, **NOT ON CLICK**.

How can I render the view `PhotosCarousel` just on click and not on displaying the page?

Comment: Will changing `<a href="javascript:jsFunction()" ...` to `<a href="#" onclick="jsFunction()" ..` accomplish what you're after?

Comment: No, it's still executing on running the page...

Comment: Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the actual call to `jsFunction` from your `href` and then handling it with jQuery.

```
<a href="#" id="photoCarouselHref">Click Me</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#photoCarouselHref").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPhotosCarousel"),
            //other ajax settings here
        });
    });
});
```

jQuery ajax documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: ok, and how can I pass the list of objects as data to the ajax request?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding exactly what you want to do.  Is there a reason you need to post your entire model to get pack the partial?  Could you post a single field, like an ID, to the Action, which would construct whatever view model you need for your partial?

Comment: In order to populate the partial, I already have all the info required in the current view. I need the list, which I have. I could easily get the content of the partial by the js function I wrote, but this way Html.Action is invoked when the page is created, not on item click. If I do an ajax request, you are right, it will be done on click, but I can't (or do not know) how to do it, how to send the list in ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

the code is ready to have multiple anchor elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <a href="@Url.Action("GetPhotosCarousel")" 
        data-id="@Model.Id" 
        data-name="@Model.Name" 
        class="call-get-photos-carousel">click</a>

    <div class="result"></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.call-get-photos-carousel').bind('click', function(event) {

        var 
            _this = this, 
            data = {'Id': $(this).data('id'), 'Name': $(this).data('name')};

        $.get($(this).attr('href'), data,  function(html) {
            $(_this).siblings('.result').html(html);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

but if you only have an anchor element, you can work in this way with ID in the element:

HTML:

```
<div>

    <a href="@Url.Action("GetPhotosCarousel")" 
        data-id="@Model.Id" 
        data-name="@Model.Name" 
        id="call-get-photos-carousel">click</a>

    <div id="result"></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#call-get-photos-carousel').bind('click', function(event) {

        var 
            _this = this, 
            data = {'Id': $(this).data('id'), 'Name': $(this).data('name')};

        $.get($(this).attr('href'), data,  function(html) {
            $('#result').html(html);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

in both cases the action is sent to the values ​​for the `Id` and `Name`.

Comment: Thank you, but I will try to be more specific.I have the "main model" Product. I need on click to open a model view containing part of this model (which is a list of items).The "main model" Product contains a list of Photos. Each Photo has an ID and Name. And, on <a  href I would need to open a partial view that has as model the list of Photos. The problem is that I need that view to be generated only on click. If I do it on js with @Html.Action, it's created on accessing the "main" view (product detail). If I do it with ajax request, I don't know how to send the list as parameter. Any idea?

Comment: on Product detail I already have the list of Photos, so there is no operation needed on GetPhotosCarousel action, except to return the partial view